# Let Authenticated User view only his/her own profile

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

In my codeigniter application following is the format of user profile

```
http://example.com/foo/view_profile/userid
```

how can I restrict a user to view others profile? that means he cannot browse any other link than his profile.

so user foobar420 can not browse following links for example

```
http://example.com/foo/view_profile/foobar250
http://example.com/foo/view_profile/
http://example.com/any-this-else
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Was going to comment this, but it's sort of an answer. Well an idea on this subject at least.

Instead of having "/view-profile/userId" why not just "/view-profile" and send the user model as an object to the page. Then you can just render the proper information only for the user who is actually logged in to the server. Assuming you have access to the user model in your server side script, this is the preferred method.

And if no user model is present, redirect to the login page.